# Android App flip Multiple third-party accounts correspond to one Google account

Tags: google-smart-home

During the process of linking from a third-party application to Google, it seems that multiple third-party accounts can be linked to a single Google account. After the A account is linked, use the B account to log in to the third-party application and initiate the link again. At this time, Google Home only displays the devices of the B account, but does not send a disconnect intent to the A account.

can you help me!!!!I hope to know where I can avoid this situation from happening！！

Comment: It sounds like you're encountering issues with Google Home not sending a disconnect intent to the A account. Can you please open [a public issue ticket](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148) and attach relevant videos when linking both? Thanks